# How to access state that's outside of scope

Tags: swift, xcode, swiftui

I am rendering multiple cards that are swipeable. I have a variable 'percentage' which increases a progress bar at the top of the screen. When a card is swiped to the right I want the bar to increase but the variable is out of scope. XCode doesn't support global scoped states so I'm a bit confused as to what to do here. I have a very simplified version of the code below.

```
import Photos
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    
    // WANT TO ACCESS THIS STATE
    @State var percent: CGFloat = 0

    var body: some View {
            ZStack{
                ForEach(imageObjectGroup){ card in
                    CardView(card: card).padding(8)
                }
            }.zIndex(1.0)
        }
    }
}

struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView()
    }
}

//Card Structure
struct CardView: View{
    @State var card: ImageObject
            DragGesture().onChanged { value in
                card.x = value.translation.width
                card.y = value.translation.height
                card.degree = 7 * (value.translation.width > 0 ? 1 : -1)
            }
            //When user stops dragging
            .onEnded { value in
                withAnimation(.interpolatingSpring(mass: 1.0, stiffness: 50, damping: 8, initialVelocity: 0)){
                        switch value.translation.width {
                            case 0...100:
                                card.x = 0; card.degree = 0; card.y = 0
                            // Keep
                            case let x where x > 100:
                                card.x = 800;
                            case (-100)...(-1):
                                card.x = 0; card.degree = 0; card.y = 0;
                            // Delete
                            case let x where x < -100:
                                card.x = -200; card.degree = -12
                                
                                //WANT TO INCREMENT HERE
                                percentage++
                            
                                default: card.x = 0; card.y = 0
                        }
                }
    }
}
```

Comment: Just add a `@Binding` inside `CardView`, then set it `CardView(card: card, percent: $percent).padding(8)`

Comment: But if you have multiple cards, it's going to be a bit more complicated

Comment: Yes, I can potentially have thousands of cards, so this state/variable would be bound to each instance?

Comment: Yeah you could do that, but then the offset will be synced between *all* the cards which you probably don't want. You should instead tie the `@State` with each object in your data source array. If you could show the full code for multiple cards, I'll write up an answer.

Comment: It's quite a long process on how I generate the cards due to some image conversions I'm doing along the way. I will try and implement what you stated as best I can it sounds like a good solution. On the side I'm thinking of how to restructure the project because this seems like an odd constraint for one state variable

Comment: I have an idea if I make a local method that increments the percentage all I have to do is access that function rather than binding the state. I can update state locally with the function

Comment: @aheze your answer worked great, if I can list you as the solution in any way let me know and thank you for the help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can pass variable as a `@Binding` to your card, but in terms of architecture it's not a good solution: card shouldn't know about progress, it's not here field of interest.

Your card should notify parent that it were swiped. So I suggest you adding a block, which card will call, and then your container view you'll increase the `progress`.

Also it looks like you're storing information about card position and rotation inside `ImageObject`. This is not very good too: you're mixing model with view state. Most probably you don't need this values `ImageObject` out of this view, so I suggest moving them directly to the view.

```
struct ContentView: View {
    
    @State var percent: Double = 0
    
    @State var imageObjectGroup = (0...100).map {
        ImageObject(title: "Title \($0)")
    }

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            ProgressView(value: percent, total: Double(imageObjectGroup.count))
                .progressViewStyle(LinearProgressViewStyle())
            ZStack{
                ForEach(imageObjectGroup){ card in
                    CardView(card: card, onAccept: {
                        percent += 1
                    }).padding(8)
                }
            }.zIndex(1.0)
        }
    }
}

//Card Structure
struct CardView: View{
    let card: ImageObject
    let onAccept: () -> Void
    
    @State private var x: CGFloat = 0
    @State private var y: CGFloat = 0
    @State private var degree: Double = 0
    
    var body: some View {
        Rectangle().foregroundColor(Color.red).frame(width: 100, height: 100)
            .overlay(Text(card.title))
            .offset(x: x, y: y)
            .rotationEffect(.degrees(degree))
            .gesture(
                
                DragGesture().onChanged { value in
                    x = value.translation.width
                    y = value.translation.height
                    degree = 7 * (value.translation.width > 0 ? 1 : -1)
                }
                //When user stops dragging
                .onEnded { value in
                    withAnimation(.interpolatingSpring(mass: 1.0, stiffness: 50, damping: 8, initialVelocity: 0)){
                        switch value.translation.width {
                        case 0...100:
                            x = 0; degree = 0; y = 0
                        // Keep
                        case let x where x > 100:
                            self.x = 800;
                        case (-100)...(-1):
                            x = 0; degree = 0; y = 0;
                        // Delete
                        case let x where x < -100:
                            self.x = -200; degree = -12
                            
                            onAccept()
                            
                        default: x = 0; y = 0
                        }
                    }
                }
            )
    }
}

struct ImageObject: Identifiable {
    let id = UUID()
    let title: String
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Because you're going to have multiple cards, it doesn't make sense to have a single `@State var percent: CGFloat = 0` property inside `ContentView` that's tied to all the cards. Instead, you want `ImageObject` to have a `percent` property, so that you can set each `Card`'s `percent` independently.

Then, use a `@Binding` inside `CardView` - this syncs all changes in `percent` to the original `imageObjectGroup` array.

```
struct ImageObject {
    var x = CGFloat(0)
    var y = CGFloat(0)
    var degree = CGFloat(0)
    var percent = CGFloat(0) /// inside `ImageObject`, not `ContentView`
}

struct ContentView: View {
    @State var imageObjectGroup = [ImageObject(), ImageObject(), ImageObject()]
    
    var body: some View {

        /// loop over `indices` in order to access `Binding` version of each `ImageObject`
        ForEach(imageObjectGroup.indices, id: \.self) { index in
            CardView(
                card: $imageObjectGroup[index] /// pass in `Binding`
            )
        }
    }
}

struct CardView: View {
    @Binding var card: ImageObject 
    
    var body: some View {
        ...
            
        card.percentage += 1 /// increment here
        
        ...
    }
}
```